# largest value of array is only being displayed in terminal

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract Max_Array{

    uint[]  myArray;
    uint val = 0;
    uint j=0;

    function push(uint i) public {
        myArray.push(i);
    }

    function getArray() public view returns(uint[]  memory) {
        return myArray;
    }

    function getLargest() public returns(uint){        
        for(j=0;j<myArray.length;j++){
            if (myArray[j]>val){
                val = myArray[j];
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question

Comment: Please specify what your problem is and what did you try.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there's no need for your `getLargest()` function to modify the state as it is ineficiently doing. If your function is called `get...()`, then it should return whatever is supposed to return without modifying the state, because you are asking it to return a value. If it has to modify something and also get the value, maybe you should name it something like `modifyXandGetY()`, which would be discouraged anyways.

Now, your `getLargest()` funciton is not a `view` or `pure` function, which means that the transaction that you send to call that function will be mined. And we know that mining happens async, so there's no point in waiting for a response from a function that modifies the state since it will not return you anything because your transaction will be broadcasted through the network and wait to be mined.

But, if you declare your function as `view` or `pure`, then when you call that function, there's no need for your transaction to be broadcasted and mined. So any node can provide you with the information that you need right way and return you a value.

So, I suggest you to declare your `getLargest` function as `view`, create a local variable called `max` and modify that variable and return it.

Take a look at my example below.
Notice how I declared two `view` functions, `getMax()` and `getMaxIndex()` functions. One that returns the max value from the array, and the other that returns the index in the array of the max value.

You can call either of these functions and they will return you the value right away. No need to modify the state.

```js
contract Max_Array{

    uint[] public myArray;

    function push(uint i) public {
        myArray.push(i);
    }

    function getArray() public view returns(uint[]  memory) {
        return myArray;
    }

    function getMax() public view returns(uint) {
        uint256 max = 0;
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
            if(myArray[i] > max){
                max = myArray[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    function getMaxIndex() public view returns(uint) {
        uint256 max = 0;
        uint256 maxIndex = 0;
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
            if(myArray[i] > max){
                max = myArray[i];
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }

}
```

**Conclusion**

When you call a function that is not declared as `view` or `pure`, it will not return you anything right away because your transaction will be broadcasted through the network and it will wait to be mined, so there's nothing to keep waiting for. But if it's a function declared `view` or `pure`, then your transaction will not be broadcasted or mined, and any node will read and provide you with that information right away. So, keep this in mind.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the clear explanation and the solution.